# Alternative for ShadowApplication.setSystemService() in Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

The setSystemService() in ShadowApplication is **Deprecated** without any additional info added into the [documentation](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowApplication.html#setSystemService(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

Does anyone know why it's been deprecated, and if there's an alternative for it?

As of version 2.2, the method is still working, but I'm concerned about possible side-effects or it getting discontinued.

Thanks,
--A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually unsure why it was deprecated, I'll ask the team and maybe we can get it better documented. I'll update the answer with any relevant info.

[ShadowContextImpl.setSystemService()](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowContextImpl.html#setSystemService(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) was [added at the same time](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/commit/ae644a046104dc0550d74b6cbf2cbe993023ff7b?diff=unified) as the one on ShadowApplication got deprecated, so it might be a good replacement, but getting to it is a bit of a pain.

I did manage to write a test that looks like this, which basically just exposes in the test what ShadowApplication.setSystemService() does behind the cover. It seems a bit hacky, but it doesn't use the deprecated function.

```
    // given
    Service service = Mockito.mock(Service.class);

    // when
    Application application = (Application) Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
    ShadowContextImpl shadowContext = (ShadowContextImpl) Robolectric.shadowOf(application.getBaseContext());
    shadowContext.setSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE, service);

    // then
    Assert.assertEquals(service, Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, i've found, that you can restore a system service to its initial state:

```
shadowContext.setSystemService(serviceName, null);
```

It is useful, when you run multiple tests.